# Inverse Fourier Transform on LCA Groups

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, fourier-analysis, operator-algebras, harmonic-analysis

I have a question regarding the theory of Fourier transforms in locally compact abelian groups.

Let $f \in L^p(G)$ we the Fourier transform of $f$ is the function $\widehat f$ on $\widehat G$, the Pontryagin dual of $G$ defined by:
$$
\widehat f(\xi) = \int_G \xi(x)f(x)dx.
$$
Moreover for $f \in L^p(\widehat G)$ we can define the inverse Fourier transform
$$
\check f(x)=\int_\widehat G \xi(x)f(\xi)d\xi.
$$

There is a Hausdorff-Young inequality:

Let $1 \leq p \leq 2$ and $p^{-1}+q^{-1}=1$. If $f \in L^p(G)$ then $\check f \in L^q(\widehat G)$, moreover,
$$
\| \widehat f\|_q \leq \|f\|_p.
$$
My question if the reverse order of this inequality is also true, more precisely, let again $1 \leq p \leq 2$ and $p^{-1}+q^{-1}=1$, but this time we start with $f \in L^q(\widehat G)$ and we want to prove that $\check f \in L^p(G)$ and the inequality:
$$
\| f\|_q \leq \| \check f\|_p \quad \text{ holds.}
$$
This would be true using the Fourier Uniqueness Theorem if I could prove that for all $\xi \in \widehat G$:
$$
\widehat{\check f}(\xi) = f(\xi),
$$
however I'm not being able to prove this.

Comment: To start with, you want $1/p +1/q=1$.

Comment: @AD-StopPutin- A mental typo, thanks!

Comment: For $p = q = 2,$ result is proven in Deitmar, Echerhoff "Principles of Harmonic analysis". For $p < 2$ it looks like you need continuous Fourier transform: $L^q(\hat{G})\to L^p(G), q > 2.$  For $G=\mathbb{R},$ Lieb, Loss "Analysis" has an exercise claiming that this map is not continuous (check scaled Gauss function).

Comment: @dsh Thank you for your reply, however my question does not regard continuity of that map since that means $ \| \check f \|_p \leq \|f\|_q$, what I'm interested in is $\| f\|_q \leq \| \check f\|_p$. It is the same as the Hausdorff-Young inequallity but instead of starting with a function in $L^p(G)$ we start with one in $L^q(\widehat G)$.